# How do I convert a string based time to hh:mm format in excel using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I need my excel output to have a column with time in format HH:mm.

My code is the following:

```
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";
string start = row.R_HourStart.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 11].Value = start;
```

But when I open the file in excel, the cell displays "10:10:00".

When I insert text in the formula bar and click enter, the cell text is changed to "10:10", which is what I want.

I've also tried using:

```
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";
string start = row.R_HourStart.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 11].LoadFromText(start);
```

I get "10:10" displayed in the cell but the formula bar displays today's full date with the hour 10:10.

Additionally, I tried:

```
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 12].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";
ws.Cells[rowNumber, 12].Value = row.R_HourEnd;
```

Which shows "10:10" in the cell but the formula bar displays the whole date and time as "22/08/2014 10:10:00".

Comment: Try to set a C# DateTime datatype instead of a String to Cells[].Value

Comment: @Fratyx i tried that...

Comment: What is the format of your row.R_HourStart before you call ToString()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you convert your time to a TimeSpan? This worked for me:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("text.xlsx"));
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

var someTime = "10:10:00";
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(someTime);
sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = timeSpan;
sheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";

package.Save();
```

Comment: Although it looks correct, the value in the cell changes to `1-1-1900 10:10:00` which is not what I want.

Comment: @HugoDelsing: It's formatted as "10:10" for me. Are you overwriting the format of the column somewhere else?

Comment: The format is correct, but if you look at the top to the actual value, it shows as `1-1-1900 10:10`. If you edit `F2` and press `enter` to save changes (without changing anything) the format is wrong again.
If you would just type 10:10 in Excel it would work differently

Comment: I'm seeing 10:10 in the cell even after F2 and pressing enter. The formula bar lists "10:10:00 AM". If I save the file to a csv format the value listed is "10:10". Excel is displaying a date/time format because it's reading the "hh:mm" as such. I'm unsure why you're seeing the "1-1-1900", what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: if you're after a duration instead of a time-of-day (where the number of hours can exceed 24) use `"[hh]:mm"` otherwise the value will just wrap around and not show a day value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because my DataTable was all strings.
Formating worked fine after i've replaced the values with paresed ones.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++)
    {
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[row, colWithDates]?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty, out dt))
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = dt;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    }

    TimeSpan ts;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[row, columnWithTimes]?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty, out ts))
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = ts;
        worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm";
    }
}
```